# phpBB open link in new tab

Tags: phpbb

I have a phpBB board 3 with prosilver style.

When a user clicks on a link in a post the  browser will open it in the same tab. Is it possible that I can change it, so that the browser opens the links in a new tab or window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete Steve's answer, if you **only** want alter links **in a post**, you **only** have to edit the `bbcode.html`  file.

1. Open `phpBB/styles/prosilver/template/bbcode.html` file,
2. Search (line 26 on last version) :

   `<!-- BEGIN url --><a href="{URL}" class="postlink">{DESCRIPTION}</a><!-- END url -->`
3. Replace it with :

   `<!-- BEGIN url --><a href="{URL}" target="_blank" class="postlink">{DESCRIPTION}</a><!-- END url -->`

I hope to be helpful,

*(Sorry for my language, I'm not fluent in English)*

Location file : https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/develop-ascraeus/phpBB/styles/prosilver/template/bbcode.html

Answer (score 2):

To make any HTML link open in a new tab, you can use the `target` attribute...

```
<a href="/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

You may need to change your PHPBB templates to add this attribute.

Comment: So I guess I have to distinguish between auto-detected links and links that have been marked by the user as a link with the [url] code?

Comment: Ah - for user submitted links going to external sources, you can use a PHPBB MOD: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=2113035

Comment: Thanks. I also find another work around here https://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/links-opening-new-windows/